# How to apply dynamic class to body tag

Tags: angularjs

I am working on Angular application.

I have multiple views and one index and I just need to apply dynamic class for one of the view and remove it for other views,

Can anyone guid me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very basic way to accomplish body classes based on view.  if you have a scope variable `$scope.view` that drives what part of your content is displayed, you can use `ng-class` where the expression compares the view variable to add dynamic classes:

```
<body ng-class="{'view-1': view === 'view1', 'view-2': view === 'view2'}">
```

Here's an example of this idea in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/Oee53MqZyWuSIFvttcpP?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Write new class and add to the required view.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ng-class on the body tag, assuming the body tag is what you are bootstrapping your angular application to?